# C++ for loop, while loop, and do while loop to generate a table of decimal numbers

Tags: c++

I need help for a starting point, really.  We must use these 3 loops to generate a table of decimal numbers, as well as the binary, octal, and hexadecimal equivalents of the decimal numbers, in the range 1-256.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what did you come up with your self?

Comment: What kind of table is it? Array, vector, text file, something else? Are you talking about string representations of numbers? Be more specific.

Comment: This question is vague, incomplete, and overly broad.  You didn't give us enough details to help you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know where to start that's... not a good sign.  Perhaps you should get together with your teacher so that you don't fall behind.

Anyway, the basic idea will be:

```
for loop counting from 1 to 256
    write counter in decimal form 
    write counter in binary form 
    write counter in hex form 
    write counter in octal form 
end loop
```

You really don't need three loops, though you can break it into three if you have to.  You can pass different format specifiers to `printf` and the like to format your output.

Comment: I think he needs three loops because the assignment is to use  each of the `for`, `while` and `do/while` language constructs, not because producing the table would require three loops.

Comment: yes I need to use a "while" loop to generate the binary numbers, a "for" loop to generate the octal numbers, and a "do..while" loop to generate hexadecimal numbers.  Also it says the program should print the results to the Console without using any string formats..

Comment: @D.Zuber: Ok, so... what have you tried. I don't mean to be rude, but if you don't even know where to start you probably have a lot of catching up to do in this class.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page to learn about specifiers: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

if you use printf and include %d then you are going to print a decimal.  If you use %x you will get the unsigned Hexidecimal of the same number.

for example:

```
int i;
for(i=1;i<=256;i++){
    printf("the number %d in dec: %d",i,i);  \\prints i
    printf("the number %d in hex: %x",i,i); \\prints i in hex.
    printf("the number %d in oct: %o",i,i);  \\prints i in oct.
}
```

OR

```
int i = 1;
while(i<=256) {
    ...
    i++;
}
```

OR

```
int i = 1;
do {
    ...
    i++;
} while (i<=256);
```

This page talks about the types of loops: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_loop_types.htm

Comment: how would u print the binary number?

Comment: also why is there the " ,i,i);" at the end of the statements in your first example?

Comment: If you read through the page I pointed to, it is a VERY valuable resource for formatting strings.  each i corresponds to a specifier (%d,%x, etc).  The specifier will convert the corresponding variable to the format of the specifier be it hex, decimal, octal, or any other specifier.

Comment: Printing Binary is trickier, basically there isn't a standard way, you can search how to do it it isn't complicated (though requires a little more in depth understanding of the shift operator >>.  There are also 2 binary representations namely big endian and little endian.